# How can NPM install packages / Node Modules so fast?

Tags: node.js, npm-install

This is not really a problem I am more like curious.

Whenever I install node packages for example via command line (npm i googleapis) it takes like 10 seconds or so but when I try to copy and paste the folder where the packages are installed it takes wayyy longer (around 3 minutes). I wondered why that is - does anyone know?

Thanks in advance.

That it takes as long as it takes to install

Answer (score -1):

When you have already ran npm install in a project. The files have been fetched and saved in the node_modules directory. These module versions are audited in the package-lock.json. When you install a single npm package, let's say

```
npm install googleapis
```

in that case only googleapis module is fetched and added to the node_modules directory while the other audited files are untouched.
Suppose googleapis has 10 files than these 10 files are added in node_modules while the other 1000s of files are untouched. This process hardly takes few seconds.

Now, when you move or copy the directory, all the 1000s of files are read from one source and written to destination which takes longer.